# Why does inserting a Hyperlink in Outlook appear to "freeze" - in my case for 45 seconds?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I attempt to insert a hyperlink in Outlook (happen to be using Outlook 2007), the "Insert Hyperlink" dialog appears, but:

1. the area underneath the "My Documents" is blank
2. The system "freezes" for 45 seconds, and I cannot do anything with Outlook.

After the 45 seconds have elapsed, the blank area fills with the folders that are to be found in "My Documents" and I can create the hyperlink as expected.

So why do I have the 45 second freeze?

Comment: Open Process Explorer, go to Outlook.exe Properties, and look at the Threads tab during the freeze.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer myself - I had one (1!) shortcut in "My Documents" that pointed to a location that did not exist (i.e. non-existent drive and path).  Deleting that short-cut reduced my time delay to <1 second.

Now why doesn't Microsoft notice the fact that this is a dead short-cut and tell me about it - that would be useful software!

P.S.  I did find another post (on Google Groups) that seemed to indicate even having valid shortcuts in one's My Documents slowed the display of the folders. No information was available as to whether those were shortcuts pointing to a local hard drive, or network drives.

Answer (score 2):

Having broken shortcuts in My Documents appears to be the culprit. On my WinXP there was one broken shortcut pointing to a non-existent mapped drive and several valid shortcuts to local folders. Removing the broken shortcut fixed the delay. Valid shortcuts appeared to have no effect.